# can we put our programming in doInBackground() in android

Tags: android

I am working on a android project>>>>
When i try to do any code in doInBackground() method in android ...it's not giving error but not running properly....
THis is my code...

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
{
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
    {

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

This code work properly when i remove **button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

My query is can we do like visibility off or type of programming in doInBackground() method....

Comment: you cant Update `UI` in `doInBackground`

Comment: write this line button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in onPostExecute(Bitmap result) it may help you

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan if we can update than why it not running...plz see my full code http://pastie.org/8567194

Comment: @mayuri yes it may work in post execute...but i want to try it in diInBackground()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must need to set visibility inside **UI** thread else it will never work. If you are in different thread use `MessageHandler` or can use `runOnUiThread`(using runnable) to set the visibility. for ex :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // set visibility here
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in doInBackground() method you can't do UI Realated Operations.

If you have to do UI Related Operations use onPreExcuteMethod() or onPostExcute()i.e,

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
 {

protected void onPreExcute(){
 // Before starting the function.
 button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) 
{

    return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
}
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
{
// after completion of the function.
//     button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

}

i think this will work or you can you use post Excute method based on your functionality

Comment: ..thanku..good answer....but we can run gui theread in non gui method also......+1

Comment: yes but we have to use runonUIThread() method to do that i won't prefer that method most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this line  `button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in your `onPreExcute()` mehod of async task

You can not update your UI in `doInBackground()`. [How to use AsyncTask in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update any UI elements in `doInBackground()` as this method is executed in a separate (non-UI) thread.

Use `onPreExecute()` for that

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
         button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
    {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: ..thanku..good answer....but we can run gui theread in non gui method also......+1

Answer (score 1):

To work on UI in doInBackground then you need to use runOnUiThread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)

                    }
                });
```

Thanks